# My ajax data is not Being Posted to php! I get an empty $_POST array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a landing page and i need to get some data from an api. I have setup the api.php but i cannot send one value from my form to the api.php

i tried many things, but i never get the post in my php.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#forma').on('submit', function(e){

        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // <-- get method of form
            url: 'api.php', // <-- get action of form
            data: {'Usernami': $("#Username").val()}, // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file

            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
}); 

</script>


 <form method="post" id="forma">
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label for="Username"> <h1 style="color: white;"> Username:</h1></label>
    <input type="texarea" name="usernami" class=" border border-white form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Enter Your Username..." required>
           <label for="Username"> <h1 style="color: white;"> <br>Use Proxy: <br> </h1></label>
               <center>
    <input type="checkbox" id="on-off-switch" name="switch1" checked>
  </center>



       <br>

      <button id="butoni" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Connect Account
      </button>

</form>


<?php

print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Is this one script or two scripts? It looks like you're trying to print `$_POST` in the script that's sending the form, not `api.php`.

Comment: where is the code of api.php'?

Comment: @Barmar It's two scripts, i have just included api.php in the index.php where the form is

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo i have not added it, as it is not relevant.  I just need the data to be sent to api.php.

Comment: I want to see the code of api.php, I wanna see how you are printing values..

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo
This is all i am doing at the moment:

<?php

print_r($_POST);
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

?>

This code below echoes a GET :/
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

Comment: change 'submit' to type='button' and change the event to ` $('#forma').on(click,`

Comment: You are actually not sending data via ajax, you are posting via form,, you type='submit'

Comment: let me know once you have tested it

Comment: When you debug, where specifically does it fail?  Use your browser's debugging tools.  Is the AJAX request being made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  Is the whole page being refreshed instead?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo i tested it. Nothing happens.

Comment: @David i get no errors. when i alert(data) i get what i want. but its just not being posted in api.php

Comment: @hellothere: What do you mean?  If the `data` result from the AJAX request is correct, then what's the problem?  All your "API" does is return the POST array.  So if it's returning a correct POST array then clearly the correct data was sent.

Comment: @David the post array is empty. i get the data from alert(data) which is within the ajax code. the api.php prints Array()

Comment: @hellothere: Ok, so go back to my original comment... Use your browser's debugging tools.  Observe the network tab.  What is being sent in the AJAX request?

Comment: @David i am getting a GET request, even though i am doing post in ajax

Comment: @hellothere: `type` is an alias for `method`, but perhaps only in certain versions of jQuery?  Try using `method` in your AJAX options.  You could also try using `$.post()` instead of `$.ajax()`.

Comment: @David i will try again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I created test api.php file where I just dumped $_POST and moved your script tag at the end of body tag and It worked for me.

```
    <html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" id="forma">
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <label for="Username"> <h1 style="color: white;"> Username:</h1></label>
    <input type="texarea" name="usernami" class=" border border-white form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Enter Your Username..." required>
           <label for="Username"> <h1 style="color: white;"> <br>Use Proxy: <br> </h1></label>
               <center>
    <input type="checkbox" id="on-off-switch" name="switch1" checked>
  </center>



       <br>

      <button id="butoni" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Connect Account
      </button>

</form>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#forma').on('submit', function(e){

        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // <-- get method of form
            url: 'api.php', // <-- get action of form
            data: {'Usernami': $("#Username").val()}, // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file

            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
}); 

</script>
</body>

<?php

print_r($_POST);
?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it. It's kind of crude looking, but its a guarantee for me...

```
$.post(
    'url',
    {
       'Usernami': $("#Username").val()
    },
    // function to handle the response
    function(data,status,xhr){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Hope it works out.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with you source code as far as i can see from your example but this could be a browser issue caching a previous script or page you could disable this and try again but the best way to test an API response is with tools like POSTMAN or insomnia

The only minor issue I found was just a small typo here

```
 <input type="texarea" name="usernami" class=" border border-white form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Enter Your Username..." required>
```

I just Changed it to type text

```
 <input type="text" name="usernami" class=" border border-white form-control" id="Username" placeholder="Enter Your Username..." required>
```

I would suggest to to try testing your API ON insomnia you can get it [here](https://insomnia.rest/download/)

Below are my result result from the tool

[image]